# Setting value of active workbook in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I for now have my workbook set up this way, in where the workbook is hard coded into the Set command, I am wondering if there is a way of doing this so I can have it where it is fluid? So no matter where this code is place (in another workbook) the code will adapt to it's new surroundings.

Does this make sense?

Below is what I am using now, what I'd like to have it do is for the `ActiveWorkbook` or something of the sort be used instead. Since this will be set at the beginning of the code and not the middle.

`Set wbOOR = Application.Workbooks("Open Order Report.xlsm")`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You're probably after `Set wbOOR = ThisWorkbook`

Just to clarify

`ThisWorkbook` will always refer to the workbook the code resides in

`ActiveWorkbook` will refer to the workbook that is active

Be careful how you use this when dealing with multiple workbooks. It really depends on what you want to achieve as to which is the best option.

Comment: +1 for explaining the difference and when and where it may be most appropriate, especially because the OP is a bit vague.

Comment: I personally never use `ActiveWorkbook` except for capturing user GUI events and even then try and avoid.

Comment: I agree. I tend to set all the workbooks I need to variables like `Set wkbMain = ThisWorkbook or Workbooks("Main")` `Set wkbProcess = Workbooks("Process")` Then I use refer to them as needed. Find it's the safest way to go as `ActiveWorkbook` can be hairy and trip the code up when least expected.

Comment: Also ActiveWorkbook and ActiveSheet implies that you have used `Activate` or `Select` somewhere which may also be questionable :)

Answer (score 3):

This is all you need

```
Set wbOOR = ActiveWorkbook
```

Comment: That's it? You know after going so far with Excel VBA, there are so many ways I find to do things, it seems I sometimes forget the simplest ways at times.  Thanks!

Comment: Re-reading your question I'm not sure if it's ActiveWorkbook or Thisworkbook you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Dim Workbk as workbook
Set Workbk = thisworkbook
```

Now everything you program will apply just for your containing macro workbook.