# "Duplicate name" errors when moving macro from XLS to Personal.xlsb

Tags: excel, vba

So I've ran this code on a local level with a data sheet that I'm working with that needs to grab the date within a certain range along with all of the rows and put it into a new workbook to be worked on. It works perfectly fine on a local level, I have no problems at all with it, but when I move the module to the `PERSONAL.XLSB` it gives an error message **(listed inline in the code below)** along with another error message if I fix the issue. My question is how do I create it so I can use this globally throughout each spreadsheet I have without having to copy and paste the code to work properly?

```
Option Explicit

'This subroutine prompts the user to select dates
Public Sub PromptUserForInputDates()

Dim strStart As String, strEnd As String, strPromptMessage As String

'Prompt the user to input the start date
strStart = InputBox("Please enter the start date")

'Validate the input string
If Not IsDate(strStart) Then
    strPromptMessage = "Oops! It looks like your entry is not a valid " & _
                       "date. Please retry with a valid date..."
    MsgBox strPromptMessage
    Exit Sub
End If

'Prompt the user to input the end date
strEnd = InputBox("Please enter the end date")

'Validate the input string
If Not IsDate(strStart) Then
    strPromptMessage = "Oops! It looks like your entry is not a valid " & _
                       "date. Please retry with a valid date..."
    MsgBox strPromptMessage
    Exit Sub
End If

'Call the next subroutine, which will do produce the output workbook
Call CreateSubsetWorkbook(strStart, strEnd)

End Sub

'This subroutine creates the new workbook based on input from the prompts
Public Sub CreateSubsetWorkbook(StartDate As String, EndDate As String)

Dim wbkOutput As Workbook
Dim wksOutput As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet
Dim lngLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, lngDateCol As Long
Dim rngFull As Range, rngResult As Range, rngTarget As Range

'Set references up-front
lngDateCol = 1 '<~ we know dates are in column A
Set wbkOutput = Workbooks.Add

'Loop through each worksheet
For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    With wks

        'Create a new worksheet in the output workbook
        Set wksOutput = wbkOutput.Sheets.Add
        wksOutput.Name = wks.Name

       '------> I receive the first error here:
       'Run-Time error '1004':
       'That name is already taken. Try a different One
       'If I change the = wks.Name = "Sheet1" it gives another error of:
       'Run-time erro '91':
       'Object variable or With block variable not set

        'Create a destination range on the new worksheet that we
        'will copy our filtered data to
        Set rngTarget = wksOutput.Cells(1, 1)

        'Identify the data range on this sheet for the autofilter step
        'by finding the last row and the last column
        lngLastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

      '---------->Error Message here for the 2nd Error message

        lngLastCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        Set rngFull = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lngLastRow, lngLastCol))

        'Apply a filter to the full range to get only rows that
        'are in between the input dates
        With rngFull
            .AutoFilter Field:=lngDateCol, _
                        Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                        Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

            'Copy only the visible cells and paste to the
            'new worksheet in our output workbook
            Set rngResult = rngFull.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            rngResult.Copy Destination:=rngTarget
        End With

        'Clear the autofilter safely
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        If .FilterMode = True Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If
    End With
Next wks

'Let the user know our macro has finished!
MsgBox "Data transferred!"

End Sub
```

I'm still new to VBA so bear with me, just trying to get a understanding of why it works at a local level perfectly fine but when trying to make the module in `PERSONAL.XLSB` it starts to give the errors and won't work. Any help would be great!

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46694369/edit) to include more information.  **Anyway,** in this case, use `ActiveWorkbook` instead of `ThisWorkbook` and you should be OK.  `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook the macro is saved in.

Comment: @cxw You could make this an answer to the question instead of just a comment.

Comment: @cxw I changed the ThisWorkbook to ActiveWorkbook and still having the same error pop up when I run the script.    'Loop through each worksheet
For Each wks In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ----> For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
This is what you are referring to correct? If so, I'm still getting the same error message. ActiveWorkbook makes it known for running the script to the active worksheet that you are working with correct?

Comment: Use `For Each wks In Workbooks("workbookNameHere.xls").Worksheets` if you want to target a specific workbook.

Comment: I changed this portion in the code, 
`'Loop through each worksheet
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        With wks
        
            'Create a new worksheet in the output workbook
            Set wksOutput = wbkOutput.Sheets.Add
            wksOutput.Name = wks.Name`
This is still giving the same error. Hopefully I'm understanding the context correctly behind `ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: @MacroMan That did it! Thank you so much! And thank you cxw Really appreciate it!!!
=D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Original

Change `ThisWorkbook` to `ActiveWorkbook`.  Per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12303098/2877364):

> `ThisWorkbook` will always refer to the workbook the code resides in
>
> `ActiveWorkbook` will refer to the workbook that is active

So when you moved the code to `PERSONAL.XLSB`, all of your references to `ThisWorkbook` suddenly pointed to `PERSONAL.XLSB` instead of the workbook containing your data.  `PERSONAL.XLSB` certainly doesn't have the input worksheet structure you expect!

#### Edit

There's an additional wrinkle!  When you call `Workbooks.Add`, the new workbook *becomes `ActiveWorkbook`*.  So what you need is:

```
...
Dim wbkInput As Workbook   ' ### New
Dim wbkOutput As Workbook
... 
'Set references up-front
lngDateCol = 1 '<~ we know dates are in column A
set wbkInput = ActiveWorkbook ' ### New - **before** creating the new workbook
Set wbkOutput = Workbooks.Add

For Each wks in wbkInput.Worksheets  ' ### Don't use ActiveWorkbook from here on down
    ...
```